# Rating Stars Missing On Rating Column In Documents Library

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have documents library with Rating column. When documents are listed I cannot see the rating stars (the icon of rating). What should I do to be able to see them ? On some documents I am able to see them but on other I am not.

Comment: What browser are you using? If IE then which version? Please try to open developer tools and see if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: Also maybe document which has rating star and which does not have different set of permissions?

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 8. What else to check to be able to see them ?

Comment: Could you please check if there are any javascript errors? To do that press f12 and go to "Script" tab.

Comment: I checked there are not javascript errors. What else should be...

Comment: Does this happen for site collection admin or only for ordinary users?

Comment: For site collection admin

Comment: If you open view properties can you see rating star?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the images for rating exist following these paths `_layouts/15/images/RatingsSmallStarFilled.png?rev=23` `_layouts/15/images/RatingsSmallStarEmpty.png?rev=23`.

Also, try enabling the rating feature on some other document library (might give some pointer).